# Trying to find the proper file path for my app, but "context" doesn't seem to exist

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to export data from the app into a text file, and to do that I understand that I need to discover the appropriate path to my app-specific file storage spot. I discovered that I should use something like `context.getExternalFilesDir()`. While this seems pretty straightforward, when I try to do `val path = context.getExternalFilesDir()`, Android Studio tells me that `context` is a function and can't be called with the arguments supplied. Seems like others don't have this problem, is there an import that I'm missing or something along those lines?

Since I had come across this line `context.getExternalFilesDir()` to be used to return the path where files should go, I had assumed it would just work, but no such luck. I've dug into it for quite a while but can't seem to figure out what to do in the case where the IDE doesn't want to recognize it.

Here are my imports, in case there's something I'm missing:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateMap
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.shadow
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalFocusManager
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.times
import com.example.packandfind.ui.theme.PackAndFindTheme
import java.io.File
```

Here's the function that contains the attempted call:

```
fun importData(): SnapshotStateMap<String, List<String>> {
    val fileName = "data.txt"
//    val path = context.getExternalFilesDir()
    val file = File(fileName)
    var data = mutableStateMapOf<String, List<String>>()

    if (file.exists())
    {

        file.forEachLine {
            val (key, value) = it.split("=")
//                var newValue = value.replace("[", "")
//                newValue = newValue.replace("]", "")
//                newValue = newValue.replace(" ", "")
            val listValue = value.split(",")

            data[key] = listValue
        }
    } else {
        data = mutableStateMapOf("New box" to listOf("location"))
    }

    return data
}
```

Comment: So where are you trying to call `context.getExternalFilesDir()`? Please include the code where you are calling this with enough context around it to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I added the entire function in which that call is located, for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to use Compose UI. In that case, a `@Composable` function can use `LocalContext.current` to obtain a valid `Context`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FruitText(fruitSize: Int) {
    // Get `resources` from the current value of LocalContext
    val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
    val fruitText = remember(resources, fruitSize) {
        resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.fruit_title, fruitSize)
    }
    Text(text = fruitText)
}
```

(from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal))

Since you seem to be unfamiliar with `Context`... I **strongly** recommend that either:

- You learn conventional Android app development (using the `View`-based UI system) via some book or course before taking on Compose UI, or
- You find some book or course that teaches you Android app development using Compose UI

Comment: "You appear to be attempting to use Compose UI."
"Attempt" is the correct word for sure! I freely admit to being a rank amateur at Kotlin and mobile app development. Thanks for your feedback, I definitely am unfamiliar with Context, not to mention also Kotlin and mobile programming in general! I will certainly take the suggestion to start out with a View-based system. Jetpack Compose was the first thing I came across and I wasn't aware I was starting out in the deep end.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to pass the context as a parameter from the activity you called from and make your function accept it.

```
fun importData(context: Context): SnapshotStateMap<String, List<String>> {
     ....
}
```